# 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED' : undeclared identifier

Tags: opencv

I am new to to OpenCV and C++ programming. I recently installed and configure OpenCV 3.0 with Visual Studio 2013 through this link: http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html

i am getting an error : 'CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED' : undeclared identifier
i have included all d headerfiles as prescribed in the link.
how can i debug this error

Comment: Hi and welcome to tack Overflow. We can't help you debug your code without seeing the relevant code. Please edit your question and copy/paste in just the relevant sections of code for this problem you have. Then we can help.

Comment: Those were renamed in openCv 3.0 try cv::LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED or similar

Answer (score 24):

In OpenCV 3.0+ the flag names changed:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56

(check cv::ImreadModes)

The flag CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED is replaced by IMREAD_UNCHANGED

Comment: It is renamed again... Try ``cv::CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED`` according to https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/da/d0a/group__imgcodecs__c.html

Comment: It drives me crazy. Why does opencv change the name of a macro from time to time?

Answer (score 7):

From version 4.0.0, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED has been changed to:

```
    IMREAD_UNCHANGED
```

https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 choices:

1. rename to IMREAD_UNCHANGED.
2. keep using CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED, but #include "opencv2/imgcodecs\legacy\constants_c.h" firstly.